How to implement a reentrancy attack in the English Auction in Solidity?
I implemented a solidity code for an English Auction where different accounts can bid during the specific period of time to win the nft.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.25;

interface IERC721 {
    function safeTransferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId) external;
    function transferFrom(address, address, uint256) external;
}

contract EnglishAuction {
    event Start();
    event End(address highestBidder, uint256 highestBid);
    event Bid(address indexed bidder, uint256 bid);
    event WithDraw(address indexed bidder, uint256 amount);

    IERC721 public nft;
    uint256 public nftId;

    address payable public seller;
    bool public started;
    bool public ended;
    uint256 public endAt;

    uint256 public highestBid;
    address public highestBidder;
    mapping (address => uint256) public bids;

    constructor (address _nft, uint256 _nftId, uint256 _startingBid) {
        nft = IERC721(_nft);
        nftId = _nftId;
        highestBid = _startingBid;
        seller = payable(msg.sender);
    }

    function start() external {
        require(!started, "Already started");
        require(msg.sender == seller, "You are not the seller");

        nft.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), nftId);
        started = true;
        endAt = block.timestamp + 60;
    
        emit Start();
    }

    function end() external {
        require(started, "Need to start first");
        require(block.timestamp >= endAt, "Auction is still going");
        require(!ended, "Auction has already finished");

        if (highestBidder != address(0)) {          
            seller.transfer(highestBid);
            nft.safeTransferFrom(address(this), highestBidder, nftId);
        } else {
            nft.safeTransferFrom(address(this), seller, nftId);
        }
        ended = true;

        emit End(highestBidder, highestBid);
    }

    function bid() external payable {
        require(started, "Not started yet");
        require(block.timestamp < endAt, "Auction ended");
        require(msg.value > highestBid, "Value < Highest Bid");

        if (highestBidder != address(0)) {
            bids[highestBidder] += highestBid;
        }

        highestBid = msg.value;
        highestBidder = msg.sender;

        emit Bid(msg.sender, msg.value);
    }

    function withdraw() external payable {
        uint256 bal = bids[msg.sender];
        bids[msg.sender] = 0;
        payable(msg.sender).transfer(bal);

        emit WithDraw(msg.sender, bal);
    }
}

In the end() method I explicitly put the sending of highest bid before the sending of the nft, since I got a task to explain the reentrancy vulnerability of this method which will occur in this case and also to write a malicious contract code to demonstrate stealing of the funds from the auction contract. But I don't understand how can I implement it, so I'm looking for some help.
I've tried to use the fallback function in the malicious contract, but at the same time how will it be called if this contract won't receive any ether, so I just got stuck.
